# How to reference this line in CSS, HTML

Tags: html, css

I am still new to CSS and HTML in general, so my knowledge is limited. I want to move some style code into css out of my HTML code. I have this:

```
<fieldset class="login"> 
   ...
   <asp:Button class="mybutton" ID="_login" runat="server" Text="Login" style="float:right; margin-right:20px;"/>
   ...
</fieldset>
```

And in CSS i reference the entire login box like this:

```
fieldset.login
{
    ...
}
```

but what I can't figure out is the equivalent of "fieldset.login" so that I can reference the `<asp:Button>` line. I've tried

```
fieldset.login Button {}
```

And other things similar, but they don't seem to work for me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is not plain HTML, this is asp.net.  Try viewing the page source after the page renders and seeing how asp.net rendered your control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use this:

```
fieldset.login .mybutton{
...
}
```

Comment: You'll also want to remind OP that class doesn't translate. The proper Asp.net property is `CssClass`.

Comment: Thank you, this also helped with other similar problems I was having.